# Portable Lua code with modules

Tags: luatex, lua, modules

*Note: I am a total beginner to writing with Lua and I'm already struggling with installing Lua modules normally (something about VS Code not running the right code, I don't know, I'll ask over at StackOverflow).  Hence, for the purposes of this question, please assume I am stupid and have never used a 'programming language' aside from LaTeX in my life.*

For a teaching-school project, I've been asked to develop a resource to help school students work on their equation-solving skills. So I've decided to create a set of algorithmically (but randomly) generated equations with worked solutions, which would be generated and printed inside (well, in the .pdf) a TeX file at compilation.  These .tex files would then be given freely to teachers to compile on their end.  I've heard that Lua is good for this, as it's well integrated with LuaLaTeX and can easily be written as a separate code file and input with

```
\directlua{ code.lua }
```

My problem is that I really want to be able to access functions like `map` and functional-programming syntax from [the LuaFun Library](https://luafun.github.io/), but I'm really struggling even installing this on my own machine.

Since I want the .tex files to basically be 'plug and play' (assuming access to a proper TeX installation), this is way too much hassle & will prevent people from using my project.  Instead, I want an easy way for me to access `map` etc., without every user having to have Lua and LuaFun already installed on their machine.

I tried copying `fun.lua` from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/luafun/luafun) and just plain inputting that before my code, but that doesn't seem to work.

So what do I do? What's the best (read: simplest, most lightweight, and portable) way to do this?

Or is this this whole enterprise fundamentally flawed, and should I use somethhing like the `python` package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should be able to input lua code with `\directlua{require('fun.lua')}`  but other than that as you show no code or error hard to sa.

Comment: Note that the lua in luatex is built in to the executable and is completely separate to any Lua you have installed as Lua on your system, and by default they use different search paths for their packages, so even if you have Lua installed and have installed (for Lua) some third party package it is not by default available to luatex's lua

Comment: Your actual use case sounds easily doable in tex and you wouldn't need lua or python or any other language, there are existing latex packages to randomise question and answer sheets

Comment: @David Carlisle (1) given that they're separate installations, how should I ensure the library exists in TeX's Lua? (2) What packages do you have in mind?

Comment: look at ctan for any `exam` package  https://ctan.org/pkg/exam-randomizechoices  for example has a relevant name (I haven't tried it) or search this site for [random question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+question) has over 700 hits

Comment: the only portable way would be to supply the lua code as you can't know where or if the user has Lua installed. Also that particular package says it depends heavily on luajit and luatex doesn't use jit by default (there is is or have been luajittex versions but somewhat experimental and not used in the default formats)

Comment: You can use the package `luapackageloader` it helps with setting paths. Especially if you are using luarocks for installing lua packages. In the end I am not too sure though if it is a good idea for you. expl3 is so versatile now, you can do what yu want through LaTeX alone.

Comment: Yes so this does seem far more complicated to do in this way than it needs to be. I guess I'll look for a different solution.  @David Carlisle `exam-randomizechoices` is just a way to put user-decided choices in random order.  I need something that allows me to run computations to generate the questions.  I'll look into `expl3` that @Yiannis Lazarides mentions.

Comment: While you're developing the package, I'd just put all the `.lua` files in the same folder as your `.tex` files (flat, without any further subdirectories). Once you want to distribute the package, you can probably just upload a `.zip` containing all the files to CTAN and they'll place them in the correct place (probably `tex/luatex/<packagename>/`). LuaTeX embeds Lua 5.3, so anything that works with that should _generally_ work with LuaTeX as well. Note that you need to enable shell escape to load any binary modules.

Comment: [TeX Live/MiKTeX already include the `penlight` module](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/penlight), which [has fairly decent functional programming support](https://lunarmodules.github.io/Penlight/manual/07-functional.md.html). If that has enough functional programming support for you, then I'd recommend just using that instead.

Comment: @Max Chernoff I'll probably end up using your first suggestion, but penlight is a great & helpful find, and closest achieves what I was originally asking. If you write it up into an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading a Lua file, LuaLaTeX will search the locations given by the following command:

```sh
lualatex '\directlua{print((package.path..";"..kpse.show_path("lua")):gsub("[;:]",string.char(10)):gsub("!",""):gsub("/+", "/").."")}\csname@@end\endcsname'
```

This gives a really long list of system-dependent paths, but only the following locations really make any sense for your purposes:

- `.` (the current directory): LuaTeX will search the current directory for any loaded files, so you can just put any `.lua` files directly in the same folder as your main `.tex` file, with no subdirectories between the two.
- `$TEXMFDIST/tex/lualatex/<packagename>/`: If you're planning on uploading the package to CTAN, then you can put the `.lua` files in the same folder as your `.sty` files.
- An absolute path: While your testing the package, something like

  ```lua
  require("/path/to/file.lua")
  ```

  will work, although this will make distributing the package quite tricky.

> My problem is that I really want to be able to access functions like map and functional-programming syntax from the LuaFun Library, but I'm really struggling even installing this on my own machine.

TeX Live and MiKTeX already include [the `penlight` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/penlight) which contains many [functional programming functions like `map`, `filter`, `zip`, etc.](https://lunarmodules.github.io/Penlight/manual/07-functional.md.html). [According to the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/penlight/penlight.pdf), to load the package you just need to run either

```lua
local penlight = require("penlight")  -- Lua
```

or

```tex
\usepackage[pl, import]{penlight} % LaTeX
```

> So I've decided to create a set of algorithmically (but randomly) generated equations with worked solutions, which would be generated and printed inside (well, in the .pdf) a TeX file at compilation.

The [`luacas` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacas) might be helpful for this.

Comment: Thank you for the help!