# Batch recompiling a file under different names

Tags: compiling, multiple-files

I've written a LuaLaTeX document that, when compiled, automatically generates a list of questions with answers for an upper-secondary class in quadratic equations.   The details are messy, but the main relevant fact is that these are generated randomly: every time I compile, I get a new random pdf.

Now I want to compile one of these pdfs for every student, but pressing the compile button in TeXStudio 20 times then manually numbering the files `main1.pdf`,`main2.pdf` etc. gets pretty tedious.  Is there any way I can automate this process?

For the sake of having a MWE, you can imagine something like

```
%!TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{random}
\newcounter{\somenumber}

\begin{document}
   \setrannum{\somenumber}{1}{2}
   The number is \somenumber.
\end{document}
```

Ideally a solution would be self-contained in the TeX file, but if it's not possible I'm open to alternatives (e.g. a bash script?).

Comment: In case anyone's curious, this is the same project as my previous post  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702705/169442

Comment: `lualatex` does understand option `-jobname` that can be used to change the basename of all output files, e.g., `for n in {1..20};do lualatex -jobname student$n main.tex; done` would create `student1.pdf`, `student2.pdf` … `student20.pdf` from `main.tex`. `latexmk` also supports `-jobname`. So if you need several LaTeX runs + MakeIndex + Biblatex + …, you can also use `latexmk` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-jobname` option of `lualatex` (and also `pdflatex` or `xelatex`) to change the basename of all output files, not only the generated PDF but also the `log`-, `aux`- etc. files.

If you need more than one LaTeX run and maybe additional runs like `biber` or `makeindex`, you can also use [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) instead of `lualatex`. `latexmk` also understands option `-jobname`. See [the manual](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf) for more information.

How to loop over numbers using `bash` or `cmd.exe` or another shell is off-topic here. But as an alternative you can use the shell-escape feature of `lualatex` (or `pdflatex` or `xelatex`) to loop, e.g.:

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname-document.tex}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
   This is \texttt{\jobname.pdf}.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\newcounter{subdocument}
\makeatletter
\@whilenum \value{subdocument}<20\do
  {%
    \stepcounter{subdocument}%
    \ShellEscape{%
      latexmk -lualatex -jobname=\string"\jobname\thesubdocument\string" \string"\jobname-document\string"
    }%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ifnum \ShellEscapeStatus = 1
  See the generated files \texttt{\jobname1.pdf} \dots{}
  \texttt{\jobname\thesubdocument.pdf}.
\else
  Nothing generated. You have to use
  \begin{quote}\ttfamily lualatex -shell-escape \jobname\end{quote}
  to generate the files.
\fi
\end{document}
```

Note: [You have to run `lualatex` with option `-shell-escape`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598818/277964).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Just a question, where am I supposed to type in `for n in {1..20}; do lualatex -jobname student$n main.tex; done`? In my TeXstudio settings?

Comment: I only have one run to do so no need for the shell escape stuff.